# is it possible to pass the whole tables in jsp to controller in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I want to pass the whole table value as an object to controller
where will I place the table value? or what king of field or input type will I use to bind the whole table? 
this is my target code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = $('#Table_data').DataTable();
var allData = table.rows().data();
document.getElementById("objectfield").value = allData;
</script>
<input type="?" name="object" id="objectfield"/>
```

what type should I use? or does it possible it in that way?

Comment: pass all htmls to controller ?

Comment: well I just wrap it in form tag, the Table_data in var table = $('#Table_data').DataTable(); is just the ID of the table in my html. I just want to pass the whole table, its columns and rows alone to controlle. is that possible?

Comment: You code can not work ? Is `allData` a json object ?

Comment: yes my code doesn't work, and yes the allData is a json object. I dont know how to pass it to a field (the <input> tag), is there a way for me to pass the table?

Comment: just parse the object into a string .

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your table JSON data and wherever you want to display just access and bind the value.
For your input field

```
document.getElementById("objectfield").value = allData.objVal;
```

Assuming that you have objVal field